# Twitter Typeahead, Knockout JS, and Twitter Bootstrap 3 not playing nicely

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js, durandal-2.0, twitter-typeahead

I'm attempting to get the [knockout-bootstrap](https://github.com/billpull/knockout-bootstrap/blob/master/src/knockout-bootstrap.js) custom binding for typeahead jQuery working with Bootstrap 3 so that I can use it with Durandal 2.0, but it isn't working quite yet. The original binding is the following:

```
koObject.bindingHandlers.typeahead = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        var $element = $(element);
        var allBindings = allBindingsAccessor();
        var typeaheadOpts = { source: koObject.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor()) };

        if (allBindings.typeaheadOptions) {
            $.each(allBindings.typeaheadOptions, function(optionName, optionValue) {
                typeaheadOpts[optionName] = koObject.utils.unwrapObservable(optionValue);
            });
        }

        $element.attr("autocomplete", "off").typeahead(typeaheadOpts);
    }
};
```

Since Bootstrap 3, typeahead is a separate plugin so I needed to make a few changes. I've modified the binding to look like this:

```
koObject.bindingHandlers.typeahead = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, bindingAccessor) {
        var $e = $(element),
            options = koObject.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());

        console.dir(options.source());

        console.dir($e);

        // passing in `null` for the `options` arguments will result in the default
        // options being used
        $e.typeahead({ 
            highlight: true,
            minLength: 2,           
        },
        {             
            source: options.source()
        }).on('typeahead:selected', function (el, datum) {
            console.dir(datum);
        }).on('typeahead:autocompleted', function (el, datum) {
            console.dir(datum);
        });

    }
};
```

I've simplified the knockout-bootstrap example HTML to only demonstrate the typeahead binding. The issue I'm having is that when typeahead tries to provide suggestions, it breaks on line [1184](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/master/dist/typeahead.bundle.js#L1184) throwing an `Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function` exception. I've attempted to create a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u7n3m/7/) for this, but it is not functional at the moment.

What am I missing to get Twitter typeahead 0.10.2 jQuery, knockout 3.1.0, Bootstrap 3.1.1, and Durandal 2.0?

Comment: Which version of typeahead are you using?  As of bootstrap 3 typeahead.js is now not a part of bootstrap so if you are using the twitter typeahead.js you need to use a different custom binding.  It also depends on whether you are using bloodhound.js or not.  Here is a working example of knockout.js and typeahead.js with bloodhound - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22055808/using-knockout-with-typeahead-js-and-bloodhound-js-v0-10

Comment: I'm using Twitter typeahead 0.10.2, knockout 3.1.0, and Bootstrap 3.1.1. I'm not using bloodhound.js as I am going to use my own suggestion engine. I will take a look at the answer you linked.

Comment: I would use Bloodhound if there was a way to suggest items that start with the first few characters inputted. Otherwise, I'm going to roll my own suggestion function to search starts-with on a ko.observableArray.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here is an updated, working version of your fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/u7n3m/8/). All I did was use the `substringMatcher` function with the `jsFrameworks` array passed into it as the typeahead source - [exactly how it is used in the typeahead.js first example](http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/).

So the `source` option inside your binding handler when you initiate typeahead becomes this:

`source: substringMatcher(options.source())`

where `options.source()` is the underlying array of your `jsFrameworks` observable array.

Here is the binding handler in full

```
ko.bindingHandlers.typeahead = {
        init: function (element, valueAccessor, bindingAccessor) {
            var substringMatcher = function (strs) {
                return function findMatches(q, cb) {
                    var matches, substringRegex;

                    // an array that will be populated with substring matches
                    matches = [];

                    // regex used to determine if a string contains the substring `q`
                    substrRegex = new RegExp(q, 'i');

                    // iterate through the pool of strings and for any string that
                    // contains the substring `q`, add it to the `matches` array
                    $.each(strs, function (i, str) {
                        // console.log(str);
                        if (substrRegex.test(str)) {
                            // the typeahead jQuery plugin expects suggestions to a
                            // JavaScript object, refer to typeahead docs for more info
                            matches.push({
                                value: str
                            });
                        }
                    });

                    cb(matches);
                };
            };
            var $e = $(element),
                options = valueAccessor();

            console.dir(options.source());

            console.dir($e);

            // passing in `null` for the `options` arguments will result in the default
            // options being used
            $e.typeahead({
                highlight: true,
                minLength: 2
            }, {
                source: substringMatcher(options.source())
            }).on('typeahead:selected', function (el, datum) {
                console.dir(datum);
            }).on('typeahead:autocompleted', function (el, datum) {
                console.dir(datum);
            });

        }
    };
```

Comment: I guess I didn't need to unwrap the valueAccessor. I'm still learning how custom bindings work and this helps a ton. Thanks!

Comment: @CameronTinker Don't quote me on this, but I'm pretty sure that the unwrapping of the `valueAccessor` was for Knockout 2.x and below. As of 3.0 and up, you don't need to do that anymore.

Comment: I see that the main thing I forgot was to make the source an object array and not a string array. And good to know about not needing to unwrap observables in Knockout 3.x.